# NodeMCU ets Jan 8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6) wet reset issue?

Tags: http, post, arduino, iot, esp8266

this is the code I'm using from the mathworks website; https://in.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/MoistureMonitor.html

I'm using it to connect a soil sensor to my NodeMCU board and then log the data via HTTP POST to ThingSpeak IOT server. My serial reading is as follows:

ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset

Please check out the code and help me out. Thanks!

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

// Network information.


     #define WIFI_NAME "Balasundar-EXT"
     #define PASSWORD "9900002967"

// Hardware information.

    #define SENSOR_POWER 6                  // Connect the power for the soil sensor here.
    #define SOIL_PIN A0                     // Connect the sensor output pin here.
    #define TIMEOUT  5000                  // Timeout for server response.
    #define SLEEP_TIME_SECONDS 1800
// ThingSpeak information.
#define NUM_FIELDS 2                               // To update more fields, increase this number and add a field label below.
#define SOIL_MOISTURE_FIELD 1                      // ThingSpeak field for soil moisture measurement.
#define ELAPSED_TIME_FIELD 2                       // ThingSpeak Field for elapsed time from startup.
#define THING_SPEAK_ADDRESS "api.thingspeak.com"
String writeAPIKey="JBNXNMFKVWQJ1NNV";             // Change this to your channel Write API key.

// Global variables. 
int numMeasure = 5;                                // Number of measurements to average.
int ADCValue = 0;                                  // Moisture sensor reading.

WiFiClient client;

  // Put your setup code here, to run once:
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin( 115200 );   // You may need to adjust the speed depending on your hardware.
    connectWifi();
    pinMode( SENSOR_POWER , OUTPUT );
    digitalWrite( SENSOR_POWER , LOW );   // Set to LOW so no power is flowing through the sensor.
}

  // Put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
void loop()
{
    // You can fill fieldData with up to 8 values to write to successive fields in your channel.
    String fieldData[ NUM_FIELDS ];  

    // You can write to multiple fields by storing data in the fieldData[] array, and changing numFields.        
    // Write the moisture data to field 1.
    fieldData[ SOIL_MOISTURE_FIELD ] = String( readSoil( numMeasure ) ); 
    Serial.print( "Soil Moisture = " );
    Serial.println( fieldData[ SOIL_MOISTURE_FIELD ] );

    // Write the elapsed time from startup to Field 2.
    fieldData[ ELAPSED_TIME_FIELD ] = String( millis() ); 

    HTTPPost( NUM_FIELDS , fieldData );

    delay( 1000 );
    Serial.print( "Goodnight for "+String( SLEEP_TIME_SECONDS ) + " Seconds" );
    ESP.deepSleep( SLEEP_TIME_SECONDS * 1000000 );
    // If you remove the sleep, add delay so you don't post to ThingSpeak too often.
    // delay( 20000 );
}

// This function reads the soil moisture sensor name times and returns the average.
long readSoil(int numAve)
{
  long ADCValue = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; i < numAve; i++ ) {
    digitalWrite( SENSOR_POWER, HIGH );  // Turn power to device on
    delay(10);    // Wait 10 milliseconds for sensor to settle
    ADCValue += analogRead( SOIL_PIN );     // Read the value from sensor
    digitalWrite( SENSOR_POWER, LOW );   // Turn power to device off
  }

  ADCValue = ADCValue / numAve;
  return ADCValue;                    // Return the moisture value.
}

// Connect to the local WiFi network
int connectWifi()
{

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        WiFi.begin( WIFI_NAME , PASSWORD );
        Serial.println( "Connecting to WiFi" );
        delay( 2500 );
    }
    Serial.println( "Connected" );  // Inform the serial monitor.
}

    // This function builds the data string for posting to ThingSpeak
    // and provides the correct format for the wifi client to communicate with ThingSpeak.
    // It will post "numFields" worth of data entries, and takes the
    // data from the fieldData parameter passed to it. 

int HTTPPost( int numFields , String fieldData[] ){

    if (client.connect( THING_SPEAK_ADDRESS , 80 )){

       // Build the Posting data string.  
       // If you have multiple fields, make sure the sting does not exceed 1440 characters.
       String postData= "api_key=" + writeAPIKey ;
       for ( int fieldNumber = 1; fieldNumber < numFields+1; fieldNumber++ ){
            String fieldName = "field" + String( fieldNumber );
            postData += "&" + fieldName + "=" + fieldData[ fieldNumber ];

            }

        // POST data via HTTP
        Serial.println( "Connecting to ThingSpeak for update..." );
        Serial.println();

        client.println( "POST /update HTTP/1.1" );
        client.println( "Host: api.thingspeak.com" );
        client.println( "Connection: close" );
        client.println( "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
        client.println( "Content-Length: " + String( postData.length() ) );
        client.println();
        client.println( postData );

        Serial.println( postData );

        String answer=getResponse();
        Serial.println( answer );
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println ( "Connection Failed" );
    }

}

// Wait for a response from the server to be available, 
//and then collect the response and build it into a string.
String getResponse(){
  String response;
  long startTime = millis();

  delay( 200 );
  while ( client.available() < 1 && (( millis() - startTime ) < TIMEOUT ) ){
        delay( 5 );
  }

  if( client.available() > 0 ){ // Get response from server
     char charIn;
     do {
         charIn = client.read(); // Read a char from the buffer.
         response += charIn;     // Append the char to the string response.
        } while ( client.available() > 0 );
    }
  client.stop();

  return response;
}
```